# find and Between two dates with query by Example<S> JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Im doing this right now on my JPARepository and it I love how it works and how easy it is to replicate with other Entitys

```
<S extends MyObject> Page<S> findAll(Example<S> example, Pageable pageRequest);
```

Now I want the same format with Example but being able to find Between 2 dates, is it possible without an @Query?

```
<S extends MyObject> Page<S> findByDateBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate, Example<S> example, Pageable pageRequest);
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example
//Currently, only SingularAttribute properties can be used for property matching

EDIT:
*After some research
I think the only way is doing a custom query, i dont like that approach because the `Example<S> example` class has a lot of propperties.*

EDIT2:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/query/FluentQuery.FetchableFluentQuery.html
FluentJPA seems a good way to archive this I dont see the way to implement this type of Functions

Comment: Don’t use `Date`. That class is long outdated and was always poorly designed. For a date use `LocalDate`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Okay I will check that, didn't know it existed. For this i think it would work either ways but ill change my stuff to LocalDate once I read a bit about it. Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, spring JPA has the method **findAllByPublicationTimeBetween()** which retrieves articles published between two given hours.

Refer: [https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query-by-date]

Comment: You mean it should work like this?
<S extends MyObject> Page<S> findAllByDateBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate, Example<S> example, Pageable pageRequest);

I get this error:
At least 3 parameter(s) provided but only 2 parameter(s) present in query.